# Problem in creating jumphost by configuring iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

I have added following ip table rules to create a jumphost. I want to ssh to the following ip defined in iptables config file.
But the problem is even after defining the iptable rules I am unable to ssh to the ip defined in iptables configuration file.While doing ssh it is showing connection timeout or connection refused. Can u please tell me what I am doing wrong or missing.

```
changes in etc/sysconfig/iptables file:

       *filter
    :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
    -A OUTPUT -d 10.18.** -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -d 10.18.** -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -d 10.18.** -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -d 10.32.** -j ACCEPT
    COMMIT

Even after iptable configuration.
while doing ssh connection is refused.
ssh 10.32.**
ssh: connect to host 10.32.** port 22: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

going by the assumption that, you have given the runtime configuration of the iptables, the issue could just be the ssh daemon itself is not running.

1. Please verify that the config you have in the file is the actual runtime config. You can do that by doing a `iptables-save > /tmp/rules.v4` and comparing with your original file.
2. Make sure ssh daemon is running and is reachable on the public/all interfaces. you can do that using the command, `netstat -nltpe | grep 22`